# A paper about putting formally proven secure "fake" vulnerabilities into your software to waste malicious actors' time

Tags: social-engineering, research

I remember seeing a tweet about an infosec research paper a while ago on how one can put a lot of "fake vulnerabilities", which resemble real vulnerabilities but are actually formally proven to be secure, into their software system to make a malicious actor waste time developing a non-existent attack, thus improves the software's security.

I forgot the title and author; do any of you remember it or any similar results?

Comment: Maybe you mean [Ghost Patches: Fake Patches for Fake Vulnerabilities](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-58469-0_27). If not use Google scholar to search [where this was cited](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=9275073569660601122&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en) or for [related papers](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=related:IgM8KUWut4AJ:scholar.google.com/&scioq=Ghost+Patches:+Fake+Patches+for+Fake+Vulnerabilities&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5).

Comment: Or [Chaff Bugs: Deterring Attackers by Making Software Buggier](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.00659): *"Rather than eliminating bugs, we instead add large numbers of bugs that are provably (but not obviously) non-exploitable. Attackers who attempt to find and exploit bugs in software will, with high probability, find an intentionally placed non-exploitable bug and waste precious resources in trying to build a working exploit."*

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes it's the second one. Oh wow, and the first ones are very interesting too! Thank you so much!